# Can you hook pyramid into twisted, skipping the wsgi part?

Tags: python, twisted, pyramid

Given that :

- WSGI doesn't play very well with async.
- Twisted ergonomics suck.
- Pyramid is very clean and component oriented.

How could I use Pyramid and Twisted ?

I can imagine making a twisted protocol to get the raw HTML request. But then I can't see how to parse it into a pyramid request objects. All documented pyramid tools seems to expect some wsgi interface at some point.

I could use [waitress code](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/blob/master/waitress/task.py) to parse the request and turn it into a WSGI env then pass the env to pyramid but that's a lot of work with many issues I'm sure I can't even imagine down the road.

I know twisted includes a WSGI server, but it implies synchronicity in the app code, which does not serve my purpose. I want to be able to use the request and response objects, renderers, routers, and others pyramid tools in a twisted asynchronous protocol, with an asynchronous, non blocking app code as well.  Hence I won't want to use WSGI.

Twisted API is verbose, heavy and uninuitive compared to any other asynchronous toolkit you'll find in Python or even other languages. Hence the critic about its ergonomics. I can use it, but training newcomers in my team to do it has a high cost. I wish to lower it.

Indeed, it packs a lot of power that I want to use.

To elaborate on my needs, I'm building a tool using crossbar.io and cyclone to have a WAMP/HTTP framework a bit friendlier to my team that the current tools. But cyclone is not as complete as pyramid, and I was hoping pyramid components were decoupled enough that the WSGI paradigm was not enforced, so I could leverage the tremendous work they did on it. All I need is an entry point : somewhere to get the HTML, and parse it into a request objet, and somewhere to take a response object, and returns HTML to the client. I wish i don't have to write a protocol manually for this, http is tricky and I'm sure I'll get it wrong in many ways.

One precision : i don't wish to use the full pyramid framework, just some components here and there, such as rooting, cookie parsing, CSRF protection, etc. I won't use their view system for it assumes a synchronous API.

Looking at Pyramid, I can see that it expects the entire request be be parsed and turned into a request object. it also returns the response as an object as well. So a part of the problem, to hook twisted and pyramid together, is to :

- get the http request text as one big chunk from twisted;
- parse it into the request object somehow (couldn't find a simple function to do this, but if I can turn it into an WSGI environ + request object, pyramid can convert it to it's format).
- get the pyramid response object and turn it into a generator of strings (an adaptor can be find since that's what WSGI does).
- Send the response back with twisted from this generator of strings.

Alternatives can be to use something simpler than pyramid like werkzeug for the glue.

Comment: Twisted has a WSGI server.  You can run normal Pyramid apps using it.  Perhaps there is some reason you don't want to do this - but you didn't say what that is (thus answers might not actually solve the problem you have, since answerers don't actually know the problem).  Similarly, I don't know what "Twisted ergonomics suck" means.  I guess it's something like "I don't like how Twisted Web works" but that could still mean a ton of different things.  Try specifically explaining the issues you have.

Comment: Yes, but the WSGI server implies synchronicity in the app code, which does not serve my purpose. I want to be able to use the request and response objects, renderes, routers, and others pyramid tools in a twisted asynchronous protocol, with an asynchronous, non blocking app code as well. Twisted API is verbose, heavy and uninuitive compared to any other asynchronous toolkit you'll find in Python or even other languages. But it packs a lot of power that I want to use. I'm looking for a way to use the pyramid components with twisted, and keep the asynchronous paradigm.

Comment: By the way, thank you for answering, Mr Calderone. I wasn't expecting a answer directly from the twisted team. I meant no offense, but really, ergonomics and ease of use is not Twisted strong point. I can use it, but training newcomers in my team to do it has a high cost, I wish to lower that.

Comment: To elaborate on my needs, I'm building a tool using crossbar.io and cyclone to have a WAMP/HTTP framework a bit friendlier to my team that the current tools. But cyclone is not as complete as pyramid, and I was hoping pyramid components were decoupled enough that the WSGI paradigm was not enforced, so I could leverage the tremendous work they did on it. All I need is an entry point : somewhere to get the HTML, and parse it into a request objet, and somewhere to take a response object, and returns HTML to the client. I wish i don't have to write a protocole manually for this, http is tricky.

Comment: One precision : i don't wish to use the full pyramid framework, just some components here and there, such as rooting, cookie parsing, CSRF protectin, etc. I won't use their view system for it assumes a synchronous api.

Comment: Going to edit the question to include these informations.

Comment: I'm sure you have reasons for saying Twisted's APIs are "verbose, heavy and uninuitive" but these are non-specific criticisms that can't easily be addressed.  How do I fix an API that's "heavy"?  I have no idea.  Regardless, I don't think you're going to get a satisfying answer here.  I think what you want is for someone to have built a Twisted/Pyramid integration layer (which is probably a lot of work if you want something good) and as far as I know, no one has.

Comment: This is a good question, vote it up.  Making 'real-time' web applications is a big topic and not all the Python frameworks do this well.  I'm a big fan of Python and Django so I'd really like to see a comprehensive (hopefully python-based) solution to this problem.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I understand it's not nice on my part to say that, it's just how I feel and how most people i have show it felt and I wanted to explain my motivation to avoid the "why do you need it" comment. Now, I don't wish to change twisted. Half of the problem is actually getting the HTML from twisted as one chunk (i can do that manually with a protocole, but i'd rather have one done for me) and sending back HTML  that I get from a generator to the client via twisted. If you can just give me hint on how to do that cleanly, that's 50 % of the equation solved.

Comment: To be clear, I don't care if you think it's nice or not.  I care about getting *high quality* criticism that can actually be acted on.  I don't need you to be nice.  I *want* you to criticize Twisted - but I want your criticisms to be real problems that can actually be addressed, not "Twisted makes me feel sad" or "Twisted reminds me too much of onions".  Perhaps those are your feelings but they're more to do with you than to do with Twisted.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "Half of the problem is actually getting the HTML from twisted as one chunk".  Are you referring to part of your question here?  If so, could you edit the question to make that more clear?  This sounds like an objective problem you're having with Twisted to which a solution could be provided - but only if you clarify what you mean.  What HTML are you talking about?  What API forces you to supply (or interpret?) it all at once instead of incrementally?

Comment: Ok, I added some detais in the question. WSGI is the bottle neck here: it expect the request to be a big HTML chunk and returns the response as a generator of strings. Either I find a way to bypass the WSGI adaptor, or I deal with it by getting the whole request from twisted and creating the twisted response from this generator.

Comment: @e-satis Have a look at Klein https://github.com/twisted/klein - also see here for complete example of how to use Klein with WAMP and Crossbar.io http://tavendo.com/blog/post/mixing-web-and-wamp-code-with-twisted-klein/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisted Web lets you interpret HTTP request bodies (regardless of content-type, HTML or otherwise) incrementally as they're received - but it doesn't make doing so very easy.  There's [a very old ticket](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/288) that we never seem to make much progress on for improving this situation.  Until it's resolved, there probably isn't a better answer than the one I'm about to give.  This incremental HTTP request body delivery, I think, is what you're looking for here (because you said you expect requests to "be a big HTML chunk").

The hook for incremental request body handling is `Request.handleContentChunk`.  You can see a complete demonstration of its use in my answer to [Python server for streaming request body content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21653519/python-server-for-streaming-request-body-content).

This gives you the data as it arrives at the server.  If you want to use Pyramid, you'll have to construct a Pyramid request that uses this data.  Most of the initialization of the Pyramid request object should be straightforward (eg filling the environ dictionary with the request headers - you can take these from `Request.requestHeaders`).  The slightly trickier part will be initializing the Pyramid request object's `body` - which is supposed to be a file-like object that provides synchronous access to the request body.

On the one hand, if you dispatch the request before the request body has been completely received then you avoid the cost of buffering the entire request body in memory.  On the other hand, if you let application code begin to read the request body then you have to deal with the circumstance that it tries to read beyond the point in the data which has actually arrived at the server.  This can be dealt with.  The `body` file-like object is expected to present a blocking interface.  All you have to do is block until the data is available.

Here's a brief (incomplete, not meant to actually work) sketch of what I mean:

```
# XXX Note: Queue is not actually thread-safe.  Use a safer primitive.
from Queue import Queue

class Body(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._buffer = Queue()
        self._pending = b""
        self._eof = False

    def read(self, how_many):
        if self._eof:
            return b""

        if self._pending == b"":
            data = self._buffer.get()
            if data is None:
                self._eof = True
                return b""
            else:
                self._pending = data

        if self._pending is None:

        result = self._pending[:how_many]
        self._pending = self._pending[how_many:]
        return result

    def _add_data(self, data):
        self._buffer.put(data)
```

You can create an instance of this type, initialize the Pyramid request object's `body` attribute with it, and then call `_add_data` on it in the Twisted Request class's `handleContentChunk` callback.

You could also implement this as an enhancement to Twisted's own WSGI server.  For the sake of simplicity, Twisted's WSGI server does read the entire request body before dispatching the request to the WSGI application - but it doesn't have to.  If this is the only problem with WSGI then it'd be better to improve the quality of the WSGI implementation and keep the interface rather than both implementing the improvement and stepping outside of the interface (tying you more closely to both Twisted and Pyramid - unnecessarily).

The second half of the problem, generating response bodies incrementally, shouldn't really be a problem.  Twisted's WSGI container will write out response data as the WSGI application object yields it.  Or if you use `twisted.web.resource` instead of the WSGI interface, you can call `request.write` as many times as you like, at any time you like (up until you call `request.finish`).  The only trick is that if you want to do this you *must* return `NOT_DONE_YET` from the `render` method.

Comment: Thank you. It gives me 5 or 6 ideas on how to solve my problem.

Comment: And sorry for the "html chunk", i meant http request text chunk, obviously.